# Warning on 'android' attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I get this warning everytime I get the "android" attribute into place. Please help.

[image: I get this warning everytime I get the "android" attribute into place. I am a beginner in android studio. Kindly help.]

Comment: complete the tag first

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add  **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in root layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
........
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to add namespace in your **Relative Layout** tag. You don't need to remember xmlns:android like code. Simply **press Alt+Enter** and follow given instructions to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    //put your radio group here

</LinearLayout>
```